# This Python code to find multiplicative modulo inverse is not giving the right result

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code

```
    def f(a,b,n1=0,n2=0):
        print('a:',a,'b:',b)
        if b==1:
            return 0,1
        elif b==0:
            print("Can't find multiplicative modulo inverse as gcd != 1")
            return 0,0
        n1,n2=f(b,a%b)
        temp=n2
        n2=n1+(a//b)*n2
        n1=temp
        return n1,n2

    n1,n2=f(8,27)
    if(n1!=0):
        print(n1)
```

I have given 8,27 as a test input, the answer should be 17 for 8%27, but my code gives 10.

PS: The second line of the code 'print('a:',a,'b:',b) has nothing to do with the algorithm, I put it for my reference to check the flow of the code.

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: You may want to also show either the equation or a link to a page with it as your code is sound and produces a result, so I am guessing the math is wrong.

Comment: I derived the equation on my own :/ .... could you help me figure out what's wrong with the math ( I had realised that the problem must be mathematical )